# Opening menu via click is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate apple website.

**HTML structure:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/page.css">




        <title>Apple</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="headerContent">
                <a class= "menuBtn"> 
                    <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href=""> 
                    <ion-icon name="logo-apple" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href=""> 
                    <ion-icon name="bag-outline" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>

            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menuContent">
                <div class="menuInput">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Store</a>

                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Mac</a>

                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">iPad</a>

                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">iPhone</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Watch</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Airpods</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Tv & Home</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Entertainment</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Accessories</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Support</a>
                    
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="list">
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macBookAir.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macBookPro.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/iMac.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macMini.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macStudio.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macPro.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/compare.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
          
        </div>

        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menuBtn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const header = document.querySelector('#header');

let IsMenuOpen = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(IsMenuOpen === false) {
        slideDown();
        header.backgroundColor = "black";
        IsMenuOpen = true;
    }else {
        slideUp();
        header.backgroundColor = "#333333";
        IsMenuOpen = false;
    }
})

function slideUp() {
    menu.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    menu.style.height = "0px";

}
slideUp();

function slideDown() {
    menu.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    menu.style.height = "100%";
    
}
```

Then there are 4 difference `css` codes.

This is the css code of the menu

```
.menu {
position: absolute;
display: flex; /* disponde gli elementi sull asse principale x */
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -5px;}

.menuContent {
margin-top: 55px;
width: 80%}

.menuInput {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #424245;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 10px;}

.menuInput input{
width: 95%;
height: 30px;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #1d1d1f;
outline: none;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;}

.menuItem {
display:flex ;
align-items: center;
height: 7%;
font-size: 18px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #424245;}

.menuItem a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #9f9f9f;
transition: all ease 0.3s;}

.menuItem a:hover {
color: white;}
```

By clicking a button on the left it should open a menu, but it doesn't. The menu is always opened even if I don't click.
If I click it remains the same, I think the JS code is correct, because I don't get any errors.

Comment: You should include the relevant css here directly; we don't know what's in your stylesheets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the relevant code in `DOMContentLoaded` ([DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)). `menuBtn` is initially unknown when loading.

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

  const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menuBtn');
  const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
  const header = document.querySelector('#header');

  let IsMenuOpen = false;

  menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(IsMenuOpen === false) {
          slideDown();
          header.backgroundColor = "black";
          IsMenuOpen = true;
      }else {
          slideUp();
          header.backgroundColor = "#333333";
          IsMenuOpen = false;
      }
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working, I think the js file is not loaded inside your html, make sure you have `<script src="index.js"/>` in the html file (pointing to the js or just use inline js in html like this:

```
<script>
 // your js here
</script>
```

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menuBtn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const header = document.querySelector('#header');

let IsMenuOpen = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(IsMenuOpen === false) {
        slideDown();
        header.backgroundColor = "black";
        IsMenuOpen = true;
    }else {
        slideUp();
        header.backgroundColor = "#333333";
        IsMenuOpen = false;
    }
})

function slideUp() {
    menu.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    menu.style.height = "0px";

}
slideUp();

function slideDown() {
    menu.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    menu.style.height = "100%";
    
}
```

```css
.menu {
position: absolute;
display: flex; /* disponde gli elementi sull asse principale x */
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -5px;}

.menuContent {
margin-top: 55px;
width: 80%}

.menuInput {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #424245;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 10px;}

.menuInput input{
width: 95%;
height: 30px;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #1d1d1f;
outline: none;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;}

.menuItem {
display:flex ;
align-items: center;
height: 7%;
font-size: 18px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #424245;}

.menuItem a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #9f9f9f;
transition: all ease 0.3s;}

.menuItem a:hover {
color: white;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/page.css">




        <title>Apple</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="headerContent">
                <a class= "menuBtn"> 
                    <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href="#"> 
                    <ion-icon name="logo-apple" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href="#"> 
                    <ion-icon name="bag-outline" class="logoImg"> </ion-icon>
                </a>

            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menuContent">
                <div class="menuInput">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Store</a>

                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Mac</a>

                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">iPad</a>

                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">iPhone</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Watch</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Airpods</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Tv & Home</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Entertainment</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Accessories</a>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="">Support</a>
                    
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="list">
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macBookAir.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macBookPro.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/iMac.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macMini.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macStudio.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/macPro.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listItem">
                <img src="image/list/compare.PNG" alt="">
            </div>
          
        </div>

        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used both tips and now it works, ty so much!